# How to add users from data in a text file

Tags: scripting, users, accounts

I have a question about creating multiple users in linux, but I need a program to work on it.
There is a new users txt file, the content is following:

```
adams:5000:Adams, John Couch:/bin/bash
atiyah:5001:Atiyah, Michael:/bin/csh
babbage:5002:Babbage, Charles:/bin/csh
baker:5003:Baker, Alan:/bin/csh
barrow:5004:Barrow, Isaac:/bin/bash
```

... (there are 70 users name in the file)

I would like to know how to write a script to add those users automatically.

Comment: What have you tried? We aren't going to write it for you, just help you figure out what is wrong with the script you are writing.

Comment: Your input is really close to a password file entry, but you could use your distribution's built-in `useradd` (or similar) command with parameters extracted from the input.

Comment: just a little hint: you can read a file line by line using the `read` command in a while loop. then, you can split up the stuff using awk, like this: `echo $line | awk -F: '{print $1}'`. Finally, use the `useradd` command like JuliePelletier suggested

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your file is named just `file`. This script will do the job:

```
USERNAME=$(cat file | cut -d: -f1)
echo "$USERNAME"

ID=$(cat file | cut -d: -f2)
echo "$ID"

USER_SHELL=$(cat file | cut -d, -f2 | cut -d: -f2)
echo "$USER_SHELL"

useradd -m -s "$USER_SHELL" -u "$ID" "$USERNAME"
```

Comment: don't use backticks.  use `$()` instead.

Comment: (0) UUOC.  (1) The OP says that the input file lists specifications for 70 users. So what is the output from  `cut -d: -f1 file` going to be? (Spoiler alert: it’s going to be a list of 70 usernames.)  (2) Why `cut -d, -f2 | cut -d: -f2`? The question says that the file lists 70 users, but shows only 5 lines, so obviously that is just ***example*** input. What if the next line is `cher:5005:Cher:/bin/bash`? Not every name will include a comma. Why not just do the obvious `cut -d: -f4` and leave the comma alone?  (3) And why are you *not* doing `cut -d: -f3` and getting the user full name?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bare minimum script to get the job done.  It makes sure that neither the username nor the uid is already in use. It makes a matching group for each user (with gid=uid) - it doesn't check if the gid or group name already exists (left as an exercise for the reader - hint: use `getent group`).

Note: the script below is untested but I've written scripts a lot like it a million times before (slight exaggeration)....there may be some minor bugs that need fixing.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
# get newusers file from first arg on cmd line or default to 'newusers.txt'
nf="${1:-newusers.txt}"

# get existing usernames and uids.
names="^($(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | paste -sd'|'))$"
 uids="^($(getent passwd | cut -d: -f3 | paste -sd'|'))$"

yesterday=$(date -d yesterday +%Y-%m-%d)
# temp file for passwords
tf=$(mktemp) ; chmod 600 "$tf"

while IFS=: read u uid gecos shell; do
    gid="$uid" ; homedir="/home/$u"
  
    useradd  -e "$yesterday" -m -d "$homedir" -c "$gecos" \
             -u "$uid" -g "$gid" -s "$shell" "$u"

    groupadd -g "$gid" "$u"
  
    # generate a random password for each user..
    p=$(makepasswd)
    echo "$u:$p" >> "$tf"
done < <(awk -F: '$1 !~ names && $2 !~ uids' names="$names" uids="$uids" "$nf")

# uncomment to warn about users not created:
#echo Users not created because the username or uid already existed: >&2
#awk -F: '$1 ~ names || $2 ~ uids' names="$names" uids="$uids" "$nf" >&2    

# uncomment the cat to display the passwords in the terminal
echo ; echo "passwords are saved in $tf"
# cat "$tf"

# set passwords using `chpasswd:
chpasswd < "$tf"
```

Use `pwgen` or `makepassword` or any similar program if `makepasswd` is not installed.  Or write your own that concatenates 4+ random 5+ letter words to get an easy to remember password at least 20 characters long - capitalise some words and insert random 1-3 digit numbers and or a punctuation symbol between each word to make the password even longer and increase the brute-force search space.  Random password generation is something that has been re-invented many times.

You can print out the usernames and passwords (from `"$tf"`) and cut them into strips (leave a few blank lines between each `user:password`) to give to each user. Tell them to change their password immediately and destroy the strip of paper. The passwords are set to expire `"$yesterday"` (requires GNU `date`), so the users should be prompted to change them the first time they login to their shell.

Comment: it would probably be better to do this in `perl`...that's what i usually use for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to add or update users from a file in batch mode: the `newusers(8)` command, which is provided by the [shadow](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/) tool swite. The tool suite should be available as a package for at least Debian and derivatives. It is available in Arch Linux, which I'm using.

For information on how to use it, see [`man newusers`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/newusers)