# How to create a user account from a text file input

Tags: accounts

Need to create a bash script to create a username from a file which contains below (username home directory full name)

drs /home/drs Paranas Theruwalan

My script:

```
!#/bin/bash
#call data from file
file="file.txt"
USERNAME=$(cat file.txt | cut -d: -f1)

USER_FULLNAME=$(cat file.txt | cut -d: -f2)

useradd -m ($USERNAME) -c ($USER_FULNAME)
```

I getting invalid username error.

Comment: Related: [How to add users from data in a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291697/how-to-add-users-from-data-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add users from data in a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291697/how-to-add-users-from-data-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

What are your separators, space or colon? You example suggests space, your code suggests colon.

You can do that in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="file.txt"
while IFS=: read USERNAME USER_HOME USER_FULLNAME; do
    useradd -m -c "$USER_FULLNAME" -d "$USER_HOME" "$USERNAME"
done < "$file"
```

This example assumes as input a file with lines like

```
drs:/home/drs:Paranas Theruwalan
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the () for using variables:
`useradd -m ${USERNAME} -c ${USER_FULNAME}`

Second check the output of username, maybe it includes invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
#call data from file
FILE="file.txt"
USERNAME=$(cut -d " " -f 1 $FILE)
USER_FULLNAME=$(cut -d " " -f 3,4 $FILE)
useradd -m -c "${USER_FULLNAME}" "${USERNAME}"
```